# Sync two local git repos connected to two remote servers

Tags: git, bitbucket

My situation is this:

I have a remote server, remote1 from which I've cloned a git repo onto my PC, local1.

I have a second remote server, remote2 from which I've cloned a git repo onto my PC, local2.

N.B. These are both supposed to be the same project as remote1 is going to be decommissioned and replaced with remote2.

I physically copied over the files from local1 into local2. Just the cp command without any git commands.

Then I did a git add on local2 and git commit and git push on local2.

Now remote2 is a clone of remote1 as are local1 and local2

I work in a corporate env and I'm coming back to this work after a few weeks.
Remote1 has move ahead with a few new branches and commits. No problem. I do a git pull on local1 and it's up to date. Now I want to propagate the same changes from local1 to local2. Now the cp isn't as useful as it'll lose branches/history info. How do I get local2 synced up with loca11? Once local2 is synced up with local1 (same as remote1) I'd like to push to remote2.
In the meantime, there have been no changes on remote2 or local2.

End goal: remote1, local1, local2, remote2 are all in sync and are the exact same and reflect the current state of remote1.

The move from local1 to local2 is what I need help with.

Thanks
-SM

Answer (score 0):

After thinking about your requirement, I believe what you need is **Git fork**.

Fork is used to clone (make copy of) existing repository on cloud source code management systems like github/bitbucket to another cloud source code management system. In simllp terms, for cloning repositories to and from cloud/remote.
It will copy all the branch history along with the files.

After forking your repo at new remote, you can always pull the changes to the local copy of that repo.